# Country Pi with PVR and no internet

Tags: raspbmc, openelec

Hello fellow Raspians...

I am hoping someone will be able to help me.
I live out in the country, so far out that I have NO internet access.
I use my rasp pi with RaspianBMC as a music and video center, playing music and videos from a 40g hdd connected to the powered usb port.
The problem is this.  I would like to be able to attach an atsc usb tvtuner to the rasp pi so that I can record tv programs from an over the air antenna.  This antenna works great on my hdtv, so i know i have a good signal.
Been reading about pvrs with rpi, but very confusing to me, front ends, back ends, add ons, etc.. And the bad part is that I can't get any add on programs using apt-get because I have NO internet.
Can someone help me set up a pvr for my pi where I don't need to depend on the internet to set it up. Or at least tell me what programs I need to add to make it work. Maybe someone can email me the software I need or tell me where to get it and what directories to put them in. A little step-by-step would also help. I can go into the city with my laptop and download programs, just can't do it with my pi.

Thanks for your consideration...

Tony